# Doing math with Python lists

Tags: python, math

I have output like this:

```
LL= [['a', 2, 3, 4, 13], ['b', 6, 7, 8, 13], ['c', 10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Instead of "13", I would like to get maximum of elements by "row" using 2, 3 ,4

where ['a', 2, 3, 4, 13] would be 4
 ['b', 6, 7, 8, 13], would be 8.

EDIT: I need to replace "13" with the max value.

Then add "14" after 13

```
for row in LL: row[5:6] = [14]
```

then replace "14" with a another inter row math.. 
How can I do this... these are tables but not matrices. 
Should use Numpy? 
Ref please so I can look up.

Comment: the changes must be necessarily in-place?

Comment: please show an example final value of one of your rows; this question is confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this in the directions what you are looking for?

```
LL= [['a', 2, 3, 4, 13], ['b', 6, 7, 8, 13], ['c', 10, 11, 12, 13]]

for row in LL:
    row[-1]= max(row[1: -1])
    row.append(14)
print LL
```

If not please describe more detailed manner your requirements.

Answer (score 5):

compute maximum of all but first and last element:

```
for row in LL:
  print max(row[1:-1])
```

add 14 to end of each row:

```
for row in LL:
  row.append(14)
```

Comment: If y = max(row[1:-1]), how would I replace "13" with y.

Comment: To replace 13 with the max value, replace `print max(row[1:-1])` with this code: `row[4] = max(row[1:-1])`